# How to show whether or not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt[4]{2})$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, ring-isomorphism

Given that the minimal polynomial for both elements is $X^4 -2$, I imagine that the fields are isomorphic but I'm finding it difficult to find a bijection between the fields (if that is indeed the approach I need to take).

I know an isomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{2})$ needs to fix $\mathbb{Q}$ so I was considering something along the lines of complex conjugation, but I've hit a dead end with that approach.

Comment: $f(\sqrt[4]4)\mapsto f(i\sqrt[4]2)$?

Comment: Note: *a* bijection trivially exists because both sets have the same cardinality ($\aleph_0$); you need to show that there is a bijective *homomorphism*.

Comment: Show that they are both isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^4-2\rangle$ and apply the fact that "being isomorphic" is an equivalence relation.